# Reducing the list of language options

Tags: settings, languages, voice-recognition, google-voice-actions

I would like to see an option that allows the list of available languages reduced to those I actually need.  When I use Voice Search, switching between English and Spanish is a pain: way too many options to choose from.  All I need is a selection of the  few languages that I speak, and not the entire list time and time again.

When I input using a keyboard, I can have different types of keyboards, eg. US international and Dutch.  It is easy to switch between those, but the voice input does not follow suit.

I don't know why Voice Input language should not be in sync with selected keyboard option.

This is on HTC Wildfire S with HTC Sense, btw.

Any views?

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close. This seems like an actual problem and it may be addressed by Android (or a manufacturer) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't. The list of available languages is a system configuration option that affects the Voice Search app, but can also be used by other apps, and by design isn't intended to be updated that often.

Google assumes that a user sets the desired language and performs actions based on it, as one tends to use the native language to perform such actions, the list is supposed to contain as much available languages as possible.

From the recent [post on the Google Blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.pt/2012/08/voice-search-arrives-in-13-new-languages.html) announcing 13 additional languages for Voice Search, it's mentioned:

> Note that you can only speak one language into the app at a time, and you may need to change your language settings to use one of these new languages.

The list itself is extensive as to allow developers to provide support according to their target users, and as mentioned, to allow users to select their own desired language.

A workaround would be to have a custom ROM limited to the desired languages.

Comment: Hm, from a software design standpoint I'd say allow the user to select a subset from the full list of languages, and call those "favorites". Then a much smoother interface can be created where you initially only get the favorites, and the whole list as an option.  There is a lot of multilingualism in the world.

It can be done.  If there is a will, there is a way.  Go, developers, go!

Comment: @HarryD I totally agree with you, a feature request @ Google [support](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/mobile/android-devices) forums may help with this.